# Reversing results in a file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file called *sum.txt*, which contains the following line:

*ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?SHA1*myTest.feature=*

If I do this:

`sed -E 's/^.* \?/rabbit/' sum.txt > sum2.txt`

In *sum2.txt*, it gives me this:

`rabbitSHA1*myTest.feature`

then this:

`sed -E 's/SHA1\*.*$/\dog/' sum2.txt > sum3.txt`

in *sum3.txt* gives me this:

`rabbitdog`

Therefore, I know my regular expressions work correctly on the original line of text in *sum.txt*.

**Objective:** What I really want to do, is to take these two pieces of the line and swap them around in the original text file, so *sum.txt* would look like:

`SHA1*myTest.feature=ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?`

I tried using sed's placeholders (`\2` and `\1`) to swap the order in which they appear in the file:

`sed -E 's/\(^.* \?\)\(SHA1\*.*$\)/\2\1/' sum.txt > sum2.txt`
or

`sed 's/\(^.* ?\)\(SHA1\*.*$\)/\2\1/' sum.txt > sum2.txt`

but it doesn’t work.  The result I am getting is this:

`ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?`

**Question:**  What am I doing wrong and should I be using AWK to achieve this instead?

**Addendum:**
The above file I have used in this use-case scenario is one of many *sum.txt* files.  Each *sum.txt* file resides in a different sub-directory along with the file that appears in the *sum.txt*.  Therefore, each *sum.txt* has a unique hash string and different *.feature* filename, sometimes even with a different file extension other than *.feature*.  For example, another *sum.txt* file that appears in a different sub-directory could look something like:

*2e1843ec8330588789790e86c72fd39903335608 ?SHA1*yetAnother.test=*

The ultimate goal is to use the sed command within a For Files recursive loop that goes through each sub-directory and modifies many *sum.txt* files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\(.*?\)\(.*\)/\2\1/' file
SHA1*myTest.feature=ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?

$ awk -F'?' '{print $2 $1 FS}' file
SHA1*myTest.feature=ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Using both solutions, the result returned is    `ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?`

Comment: Yes it does work, see above. You're doing something wrong or your input doesn't look like you say it does in your question.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I'm trying to work out why it didn't work out the first time.  I tried it multiple times before replying with no joy.  My mistake - apologies, and my thanks for your answer.

Comment: I know why it wasn't working for me originally.  My files are saved in Carriage Return Line Feed (CLRF) format.  When changed to Line Feed (LF), your solution works.  Is there a regular expression that can be used with sed or awk to accommodate this?  I do not know why my files are saved in this way and now this is my next problem to solve.

Comment: With GNU awk (for multi-char RS) you can use `awk -v RS='\r?\n' 'script' file`. In any awk you can add `sub(/\r/,""); ` before the `print`. The usual advice though is to run `dos2unix` or similar on the file first to remove the `\r`s.

Comment: I will certainly have a look at that.  Thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You can match till `?` as captured group 1, and the rest in group 2, and then swap them around in replacement:

```
sed -E 's/^([^?]+\?)(.*)/\2\1/' sum.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^?]+\?)(.*)/\2\1/' <<<'ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?SHA1*myTest.feature='
SHA1*myTest.feature=ccc7b3c6501338da68d0484d204994d82bbd9487 ?
```

Comment: Although this does work for the use-case I provided, this would not be suitable for multiple files that would contain a unique hash string and filename.  The files are being generated for every .feature file I have.  If I have multiple .feature files spread across multiple sub-directories, this solution wouldn't work in a For Files loop.